# What is the fast way to find the which section a number belong to (using vector in c++)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, vector, stl

There are many initial ip addresses and end ip addresses like:

1. 0.0.0.0     0.255.255.255
2. 1.0.0.0     1.51.255.255
3. 1.52.0.0    1.52.255.255
4. ....

I stored every initial ip address in a vector like:
0.0.0.0 -> 1.0.0.0 -> 1.52.0.0 -> .....

When there is a ip address come ,like "1.52.4.5", how to find out which section it belongs to (in this situation it belongs to the third section)?

I implemented a some kind of binary search to do this , but it is to slow.
And I find that std::binary_search is more faster than binary search implemented by my self.

But std::binary_search cannot do ip search like the above situation.
Is there any fast built-in functions, like std::binary_search, can do this?

How I do:

I convert the ip address to unsigned int like:
0.0.0.0 -> 0;
 0.255.255.255 -> 16777215

And I stored a 'from' and 'to' in a vector like :
vector.push_back(from) and vector.push_back(to).

And then I push all these vector into a 2-D vector like:
 vector < vector < unsigned int> >.

When a ip address come, first I convert it to unsigned int and then do binary search in my 2-D vector:

```
int bsearch(vector<vector<unsigned int> >arr, unsigned int key){
 int low = 0;
 int high = arr.size() - 1 ;
 int mid = 0;
 while(low <= high){
     mid = (low + high)/2;
     if(key>arr[mid][1]){
         low = mid +1;
     }
     else if(key < arr[mid][0]){
         high = mid-1;
     }
     else{
         return mid;
     }
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to identify if an IP address is class A, B, C, etc?

Comment: How are the IP addresses stored in the vector? Are they strings?

Comment: Please provide a test case, since that will contain all the relevant information to answer you question.

Comment: I would think either `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` would be more appropriate for this search. Both are logarithmic complexity, and provided you do some conversions on your values as you store them (i.e as 32bit unsigned values) would be plenty fast, even with a custom comparator.

Comment: While you have good answers already, I'd like to add two more things that's a concern for me: How many addresses do you have that even a badly-implemented binary search causes a noticeable slowdown? How slow is too slow? Also, don't forget that there's IPv6, so maybe `sockaddr_t` would be an appropriate representation for your addresses rather.

Comment: I supplement my code @ray. Thank you very much~

Comment: I supplement the way how I store ip address, thank you~ @TristanBrindle

Comment: I supplement how I did and my code. Thank you~ @xaxxon

Comment: Thanks for your advice~ I have seen `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` but I have no idea how to use them to do search when there only 'start ip' and  'end ip'?

Comment: I have 400000 tuples(one 'from' and one 'to'). My badly-implemented code cause I only can do searching 10-50 times on a second but I want do more than 1000 times searching in a second. @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: First thing to fix is that every time you run that function you copy the whole vector. Please, the reasons are basic C++ knowledge, you need to go through a tutorial! Also, you even use a vector of vectors, making things worse even if you didn't copy it due to lacking "locality of reference".

Comment: Using a binary search you need `log2(400k)<19` comparisons. Doing that 1000 times per second gives you 53 microseconds for each, which doesn't sound too little. You could also consider using a so-called trie branching on 4 or 8 bits. In any case make sure you separate the lookup interface from the implementation behind it, so that you can easily experiment with different implementations.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You are right, I made a rookie mistake.  I add `&` before parameters. I should review C++ tutorial. T T

Comment: @York: Using a `std::vector` to store a begin/end pair is a bit inconvenient, especially since there's a `std::pair<Type1, Type2>`.

Comment: @MSalters Thank you! I haven't seen this before, I will try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you stored the IP addresses, but if you stored them as a String this is quite a slowdown.

As IPv4-addresses are 4 bytes, you could store the *'from'* and *'to'* addresses in a single 64 bit **long** variable.

If your list does not grow or has at least a limited size, you can store it in an array (**long[]**) for avoiding any object access overhead. Binary search should be fast enough for nearly all purposes (**O(log n)**).

But if your list is very long and the first byte of *'from'* and *'to'* are always the same, you can divide your ranges in 256 buckets in each all intervals with the corresponding first byte of the IP-address. In each bucket you can perform a binary search. This reduces the search by at most 8 compares (not much, but may be enough).

Comment: `std::uint64_t` would be a better choice

Comment: Why use anything but `uint32_t`?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt: You need the 'from' and the 'to' IP-address of the interval. Each has 4 bytes = 32 bits.

Comment: True, I missed that part. I'd still consider using two separate objects (even if aggregated in a struct) for the two IPv4 addresses they represent.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt: may be that is the even better better way. Or use the odd indexes of a 32 bit array for 'from'  and the even ones for the 'to' entries to avoid any bit  masks for the comparison.

Comment: Thank you ~ I stored ip-address as unsigned int.  Maybe the bottleneck is the search way  I implemented?

Comment: @MrSmith42: It would be even simpler to use two arrays. Look up the `lower_bound` in the array of start addresses, and then check the corresponding entry in the array of end adresses. In that way, you don't need extra types nor custom predicates.

Comment: @MSalters: using one array may be faster, because the 'to' field will very likely be already in the CPU-cache. But only profiling can show if there is a performance difference.

Comment: @MrSmith42: Actually, since that one array will be twice as big, it has a worse cache performance. You're filling the cache with useless "to" addresses. In my solution, after the O(lg N) search for the begin, there's just a single probe O(1) to check the end.

Comment: @MSalters: If the intervals are not distinct we may need to check more than one 'to' but I still think you are right that we need far less 'to'-compares so two arrays are likely to be better for the CPU-cache. Because both implementations are so similar, I would profile both just to be sure.

Comment: @MrSmith42: In the case of overlapping intervals, the `lower_bound` of the address is already incorrect. Consider the simplified intervals [1,10] and [3,5]. Looking for 6, we'd find the `lower_bound` 3. But overlapping intervals apparently don't occur, as the question doesn't specify how to disambiguate them. Again with [1,10] and [3,5], what should the result be for 4?

Comment: @MSalters: depends on what you want. I would answer with the most specific interval, or all matching intervals.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to use `lower_bound` on a ordered vector:

```
struct addr
{
    int _1;
    int _2;
    int _3;
    int _4;
};

struct addr_comp
{
    bool operator()(const addr& ip_1, const addr& ip_2) const {

        if (ip_1._1 < ip_2._1)
            return true;

        if (ip_1._1 == ip_2._1 && ip_1._2 < ip_2._2)
            return true;

        if (ip_1._1 == ip_2._1 && ip_1._2 == ip_2._2  &&  ip_1._3 < ip_2._3)
            return true;

        if (ip_1._1 == ip_2._1 && ip_1._2 == ip_2._2  &&  ip_1._3 == ip_2._3 && ip_1._4 < ip_2._4)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

vector<addr> initial_ip;


int main()
{
    lower_bound(initial_ip.begin(), initial_ip.end(), v, addr_comp());


    return 0;
}
```

If you need more performance, you can implement a custom  binary search that compute the insertion point of a new element inside the vector. The insertion point is the position of searched section.
I edited my answer to add the custom search:

```
template<typename IT, typename V, typename COMP> IT binary_insertion_point(IT start, IT end, const V& value, COMP less)
{
    IT result = end;
    while ( start < end)
    {
        IT& mid = start + ((end - start) / 2);

        if ( less(*mid,value) )
        {
            result = mid;
            start = mid;
        }
        else if ( less(value, *mid) )
        {
            end = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            result = mid;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You need to handle the case of ip address lowest of all initial ip stored in the vector.

binary_insertion_point(initial_ip.begin(), initial_ip.end(), v, addr_comp());